# Trying to import excel file to Jtable, console is throwing IOExceltion

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, apache-poi, ioexception

I have this button that would both take an excel sheet and print it in a Jtable, but im getting an IOException error.

I am using netBeans with additional libraries from Apache POI

I have tried creating a separate function that would import the Excel file and used it in my button

Below is the code i used in my button

```
try {
            InputStream inStr = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/leandro/Desktop/TRUMAX/Clients JULY 2019.xlsx");
            Workbook wBook = WorkbookFactory.create(inStr);
            Sheet sheet = (Sheet) wBook.getSheetAt(0); 

            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)//iterate all rows from the first one to the last - make i 1 if you have headers or w/e
            {
                Row row;
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                Cell cell_ID = row.getCell(0);//the first column cell in the row
                Cell cell_CNAME = row.getCell(1);//the second column cell in the row

                String id = cell_ID.getStringCellValue();
                String clientname = cell_CNAME.getStringCellValue();

                //And here you just add them to your table or w/e
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
                model.addRow(new Object[]{id, clientname});
            }
// TODO add your handling code here:
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(testinternalexcel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

When ever i click the button it throws an IOException error in the console

some lines include:

```
Jul 31, 2019 1:59:39 PM trumax.testinternalexcel jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:351)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:232)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:301)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:134)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Comment: Add the missing jar to your classpath?

Comment: That was it, i added only the main apache poi jars, i didn't know that there were other jar file, thanks!